# Statements after END in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I came across an interesting problem today.  I was altering a stored procedure and put a select statement at the very end.  It was meant to be temporary and just for working with the data.  I was surprised to find out later that the statement got saved and was executing whenever the SP ran.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

-- Comments usually go here and are saved as part of the SP
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
    @param INT
AS
BEGIN
    --Your normal SQL statements here
END

--You can also add SQL statements here
select * from LargeTable

--You have access to the params
select @param
```

It makes sense that everything is saved, not just what is inside BEGIN/END, otherwise the comments and `SET ANSI_NULLS`, etc. would disappear.  I'm a little confused with what starts where, so I have a few questions:

1. `SET ANSI_NULLS` gets saved as part of the SP.  I have confirmed that each SP has its own value.  How does SQL Server know to save this as part of the SP since it's not referenced before?  Does it do a full scan of the current environment state, then when `ALTER PROCEDURE` runs it saves the state (possibly only non-default values)?
2. Apparently the BEGIN/END are optional and have no intrinsic meaning. Why are they even included then?  They give a false sense of scope that doesn't exist.  It seems to me no BEGIN/END and a GO at the end would make the most sense.

Comment: BEGIN/END are used for scope, like containing multiple statements in an IF/WHILE/etc.  Frankly, TSQL is atrocious to work with compared to PLSQL - which is much more structured/organized in how it uses BEGIN/END, and uses semi-colons to terminate lines.  Like how TSQL requires a semi-colon before a WITH/CTE if you declare variables before it...:/  Anyone with C based language experience can be given PLSQL & be able to read it.  Can't say that for TSQL...

Comment: @OMG - So what "scope" does it give in this case?  The only thing I can imagine is if you declare a variable inside the BEGIN/END it's not available outside.  Why would you ever put SQL statements outside; why wouldn't you put everything outside and no BEGIN/END?

Comment: The example is valid, I didn't say it was sapient ;)

Comment: @OMG: That's fine, I'm just thinking/rambling out loud.  It wouldn't be the first time I come across something that doesn't make sense to me.  I have been guilty if it myself as well, of course.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI NULLS and QUOTED IDENTIFIERS are stored as metadata attributes of the stored procedure code. You can review these settings via

```
select * from sys.sql_modules
```

When a procedure is saved, these attributes are set to whatever they are for the connection through which the procedure is being saved. This can lead to irritating inconsistancies, so be wary.

As for BEGIN/END, it's exactly as @bobs says -- they denote code blocks, they do not denote the start and end of stored procedure code. (Functions, yes, procedures, no.)  As you say, `no BEGIN/END and a GO at the end would make the most sense` is the way I've been doing it for years.

Technically, SQL will (attempt to) save everything in a batch as part of the stored procedure -- that is, all the text you submit, as broken up by GO statements (if any).  If you stuck a RETURN statement right before your ad hoc queries, they'd be included in the code but never run.

Comment: +1 for `sys.sql_modules` and that function DO use `BEGIN/END`.  Only problem with `GO` at the end is that it's not generated by the modify option, so the next time it's not there.  But at least the `BEGIN/END` isn't there either.

Answer (score 6):

The `BEGIN...END` defines a block of code.  It doesn't define the beginning and ending of a script or procedure.  But, I agree it can be confusing.

The SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET ANSI_NULLS settings are saved but not the other settings.  Check out Interoperability [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That answers my first question, thanks: `The Database Engine saves the settings of both SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER and SET ANSI_NULLS when a Transact-SQL procedure is created or modified ... Other SET options, such as SET ARITHABORT, SET ANSI_WARNINGS, or SET ANSI_PADDINGS are not saved when a procedure is created or modified. If the logic of the procedure depends on a particular setting, include a SET statement at the start of the procedure to guarantee the appropriate setting.`

Answer (score 1):

> Encloses a series of Transact-SQL
>   statements so that a group of
>   Transact-SQL statements can be
>   executed. `BEGIN` and `END` are
>   control-of-flow language keywords.

When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `ON`, a `SELECT` statement that uses `WHERE` column_name = `NULL` returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A `SELECT` statement that uses `WHERE` column_name <> `NULL` returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.

When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A `SELECT` statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that have null values in column_name. A `SELECT` statement that uses `WHERE` column_name <> `NULL` returns the rows that have nonnull values in the column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses `WHERE` column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not `NULL`.

When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `ON`, all comparisons against a null value evaluate to UNKNOWN. When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, comparisons of all data against a null value evaluate to TRUE if the data value is NULL. If `SET ANSI_NULLS` is not specified, the setting of the `ANSI_NULLS` option of the current database applies. For more information about the `ANSI_NULLS` database option, see `ALTER DATABASE` (Transact-SQL) and Setting Database Options.

`SET ANSI_NULLS ON` affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is `NULL` or a literal `NULL`. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.

For a script to work as intended, regardless of the `ANSI_NULLS` database option or the setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS`, use IS `NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in comparisons that might contain null values.

`SET ANSI_NULLS` should be set to ON for executing distributed queries.

SET ANSI_NULLS must also be ON when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, any `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements on tables with indexes on computed columns or indexed views will fail. SQL Server will return an error that lists all SET options that violate the required values. Also, when you execute a `SELECT` statement, if `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, SQL Server will ignore the index values on computed columns or views and resolve the select operation as if there were no such indexes on the tables or views.

Comment: Good info on ANSI_NULLS, but not directly relevant to the question.  I didn't know about the rules in the last paragraph and it's always good to learn more.