# Are BEGIN / END keywords required in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I need to use Begin / End Blocks and the Go keyword in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180279/when-do-i-need-to-use-begin-end-blocks-and-the-go-keyword-in-sql-server)

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoSomething
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert lots of statements in here, including other stored procedures.
END
```

Do you need the BEGIN and END? Does it make ANY difference if you have them or not?

Comment: tried really? any difference that u found?

Comment: if I have multiple statements inside the "BEGIN" .... what if an "exception" happens for ONE of them and I get an error. Will it continue executing the other lines of code or will it exit the "BEGIN?"

Comment: No it counts the rest of the batch as the stored proc definition (even after the `END` if a `BEGIN ... END` is present). So it is quite easy to inadvertantly leave a recursive `EXEC` call in there!

Comment: In `IF` statements and loops, `BEGIN ... END` is good practice. In stored procedures, it should be considered bad practice; it gives a false sense of encapsulation. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188557/statements-after-end-in-stored-procedure).

Answer (score 15):

They are *optional*.

From MSDN - [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

From the definition of the command -

> AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }

And later on in the page:

> { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
>
> One or more Transact-SQL statements comprising the body of the procedure. You can use the optional BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the statements.

Answer (score 7):

As indicated in [the CREATE PROCEDURE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx), they are optional.

> { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
>
> One or more
>   Transact-SQL statements comprising the body of the procedure. You can
>   use the ***optional*** [emphasis added] BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the statements. For
>   information, see the Best Practices, General Remarks, and Limitations
>   and Restrictions sections that follow.

Personally, I always include them, but that's just me.